# How to back up emails WITH IMAGES in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

When using a .pst file to back up emails in Outlook, I find that many of the images and pictures are missing from the backup file. Apparently, Outlook does not download many images at the first place. The images are not in the attachments. They are in the body of the message. **They show up in the text when opened in browser.**

How could I include all pictures into the .pst file?

Comment: What images and pictures? Attachments? Images in the body? If in the body, is the body HTML and the images are links? Or are the images embedded? Please provide more information.

Comment: @teylyn I have now added some information.